# PySide Drop down menu

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am making a application in PySide and I want to click on a toolbutton (which has a custom image) and that would trigger a drop down menu which would have different options. Is there some sort of Widget that does this, or would I have to make a custom one.  If yes, how would I do this.  I have not tried anything yet, I just need to know how to go about doing it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems u are using the PySide.QtGui.QToolButton widget.

It has a function

```
YourToolButton.setMenu(menu)
```

Which associates a menu with the button.You have to pass a QMenu object which you can create just like any other widget.

Use

```
YourToolButton.setPopupMode(mode)
```

and set mode to 'InstantPopup' to get instant menu.

To add your options,use

```
YourMenu.addAction(icon, text, receiver, member[, shortcut=0])
```

Set the icon and text.The 'receiver' is a function to handle the triggered action.
Refer the Pyside Docs.